# Jenkins behind proxy - illegal character in proxy url

Tags: linux, proxy, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins behind corporate proxy. My proxy password contains special characters something like 'P@ssw0rd'.

Getting below exception while building pipeline

```
 Started by user unknown or anonymous
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 38: http://user:P%40ssw0rd@internet_proxy.abc.com:80
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3387)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3236)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3155)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:673)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1751)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to create http proxy uri
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1755)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:351)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:198)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm getting a positive response in validating proxy with test URL.

Proxy URL snippet -

```
http://user:P%40ssw0rd@internet_proxy.abc.com:80
```

Answer (score 2):

Any "special" character needs to be percent-escaped, *particularly* `@`, because that is the separator between the password and hostname portions of a URL.

Comment: My password contains '@' from logs i could see that jenkins converting @ into '%40'. I'm assuming jenkins not allowing any special characters in password.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting quotes around the password or use a \ ( backslash before the special characters.

Comment: This is a URL, not a shell.